# How can you use the Magento API to query a list of orders with multiple status values?

Tags: xml, soap, magento

I am trying to use Magento SOAP to query an order list. I've got it pulling values for a single status but need to pull multiple values. (ex: Processing, Complete, etc.)

Here's my code for one status value...

```
$orderListRaw = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.list',
array(array('status'=>array('='=>$orderstatus))));
```

Any insight into having it pull for multiple values?

Queries are all from a remote server so I can't use Mage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look for this KnowledgeBase article to get the right conditions http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections

```
$orderListRaw = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.list',
```

array(array('status'=>array('in'=>array('pending','cancelled')))));

You might need to use numeric values for statuses or just don't send any conditions to it to get all statuses